# Conditional field on checkbox is not woking

Tags: 8, javascript

If the checkbox is checked then it will show the textbox else not, for this purpose i've written this code. But it is not working, even the textfield is not showing.
what do i need to change in this code ?

```
      $form['details'] = array(
       '#type' => 'fieldset',
       '#title' => $this->t('Details'),
      );

      $form['details']['field_type'] = array(
       '#type'    => 'checkbox',
       '#default_value' => 0,
       '#title'   => t('Choose entry type.')
      );

     $form['details']['text'] = array(
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => t('Enter the text'),
      '#states'        => array(
         'visible'      => array(
           ':input[name="field_type"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
         ),
       ),
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this code ... It works !!

```
$form['field_type'] = array(
  '#type'    => 'checkbox',
  '#default_value' => 0,
  '#title'   => t('Choose entry type.')
);

$form['text'] = array(
  '#type'          => 'textfield',
  '#title'         => t('Enter the text'),
  '#states'        => array(
     'visible'      => array(
       ':input[name="field_type"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
     ),
   ),
);
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: did u copy and pasted the same code..?? Flush your cache and check once  because i tried same code and it worked fine

Comment: yes, it's working now, but its not working under 'fieldset'.

Comment: So if u can update the whole code i can help you out with something

Comment: please check my updated code in the OP

Comment: I copied the same code and placed in my form it works ..Please clear the cache and try

Comment: `array('checked' => TRUE)` solved the issue, other issues i was having due to some other reasons. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Attribute #states does not work with some types such as date / datetime.

You have to add your field into a container and apply the #states to this container.

```
$form['filters']['start-do'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Filter by start date'),
);
$form['filters']['container'] = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#states' => array(
    'invisible' => array(
      'input[name="start-do"]' => array('checked' => FALSE)
    )
  )
);
$form['filters']['container']['start'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => t('Start Date'),
  '#description' => t('Show hours that started after this date.'),
);
```